# Is checking error queue for returning error done correctly in SSL_CTX_use_certificate_chain_file?

Tags: linux, openssl

I see the code in ssl/ssl_rsa.c ( use_certificate_chain_file() )

```
err = ERR_peek_last_error();
if (ERR_GET_LIB(err) == ERR_LIB_PEM
    && ERR_GET_REASON(err) == PEM_R_NO_START_LINE)
{
    ERR_clear_error();
}
else
{
    ret = 0;
}
```

So if there is no error in the queue, as per documentation ERR_peek_last_error() returns 0.
This fails this function.
I'm seeing, for some reason one executable linked to openssl lib succeeds loading certificate by passing this if condition and another executable fails since last error is 0.

I kept traces in openssl for debugging..

**EXE1 (loads certificate)**

- PEM_bytes_read_bio called
- PEM_read_bio called
- BIO fgets reads, len=0 :
- ERR_get_state called, state = 80c0f20
- err-clear_data() called from, file=crypto/err/err.c , line=369
- BIO_gets, returns 0
- BIO_gets, error logged, PEM_R_NO_START_LINE
- Error in PEM_read_bio
- ERR_get_state called, state = 80c0f20
- Trying to get errors from queue, get_error_values called from file=crypto/err/err.c, line=446
- ERR_get_state called, state = 80c0f20
- err-clear_data() called from, file=crypto/err/err.c , line=710
- PEM_bytes_read_bio returns NULL
- ERR_peek_last_error called from, file=crypto/err/err.c, line=421
- ERR_get_state called, state = 80c0f20
- Trying to get errors from queue, get_error_values called from file=crypto/err/err.c, line=446
- err = 906d06c, GET_LIB = 9, GET_REASON = 108
- ERR_print_errors_fp called
- ERR_print_errors_cb called
- ERR_get_error_line_data called from, file=crypto/err/err.c, line=399
- ERR_get_state called, state = 80c0f20
- Trying to get errors from queue, get_error_values called from file=crypto/err/err.c, line=446
- 0:error:0906D06C:PEM routines:PEM_read_bio:no start line:crypto/pem/pem_lib.c:693:Expecting: CERTIFICATE

**EXE2 (fails loading certificate)**

- PEM_bytes_read_bio called
- PEM_read_bio called
- BIO fgets reads, len=0 :
- ERR_get_state called, state = a6d0748
- err-clear_data() called from, file=crypto/err/err.c , line=369
- BIO_gets, returns 0
- BIO_gets, error logged, PEM_R_NO_START_LINE
- Error in PEM_read_bio
- ERR_get_state called, state = a6d0748
- Trying to get errors from queue, get_error_values called from file=crypto/err/err.c, line=446
- ERR_get_state called, state = a6d0748
- err-clear_data() called from, file=crypto/err/err.c , line=710
- PEM_bytes_read_bio returns NULL
- err = 0, GET_LIB = 0, GET_REASON = 0
- some other error
- ERR_print_errors_fp called
- ERR_print_errors_cb called
- ERR_get_error_line_data called from, file=crypto/err/err.c, line=399
- ERR_get_state called, state = a6d0748
- Trying to get errors from queue, get_error_values called from file=crypto/err/err.c, line=446
- 0:error:0906D06C:PEM routines:PEM_read_bio:no start line:crypto/pem/pem_lib.c:693:Expecting: CERTIFICATE

The strange thing is that, EXE2 while checking the error queue retuns 0 and just after when printing the error queue before clearing it actually gives the exact error as expected..

*ERR_peek_last_error called from, file=crypto/err/err.c, line=421*
Above trace is missing in EXE2 and I've no idea how it gets the error 0..

Any help on identifying what is going wrong is highly appreciated..